# Function to Lambda conversion

Tags: function, lambda

Im trying to convert this function into a lambda function but I am unsure of how to utilize the rotate in lambda. Any help is appreciated.Function is below.

```
list = [1, 2, 5, 9, 11, 43, 16, 2]

def rotate(l, n):
    return l[-n:] + l[:-n]

rotate(list, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is a bit tautalogicial, but you can invoke the function in the lambda with the same parameters, something like this:

```
lambda l, n: rotate(l, n)
```

and even give it a name:

```
my_rotate = lambda l, n: rotate(l, n)
```

But after all that, you're just wrapping `rotate` in an identical function, so you're better off using rotate on it's own.  As a preference, lambdas should be used for extremely simple functions in the next few lines